# java - throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound not works

Tags: java, spring, exception, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to handle 404 error using an `@ControllerAdvice` in a Spring MVC application totally configured using Java configuration.

Here you have my conf:

```java
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container)
    {

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        dispatcherServlet.setServletContext(container);
        dispatcherServlet.refresh();

        CookieHelper cookie = (CookieHelper) dispatcherServlet.getBean("cookie");
        final Gson gson = (Gson) dispatcherServlet.getBean("gson");

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = container.addFilter("BaseFilter", new BaseFilter(cookie, gson));
        filter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/coolers/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/hothouses/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/lang/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/organizations/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/reworks/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/select/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/volumes/*");
    }

}
```

and my GlobalExceptionHandlerController:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handle() {
      System.out.println("test test test test");
      return "error/index";
    }
}
```

**NoHandlerFoundException not firing?**

Comment: Are you doing any action which would result in NoHandlerFoundException?

Comment: Even though thread is older, got in to same situation, written answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, got it resolved. Below given steps to solve the same.

1. Create a class `GlobalExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleNotFoundError(Exception ex) 
    {
        return "redirect:/yourCustom404page";
    }
}
```

2. By default, when a page/resource does not exist the servlet container will render a default 404 page. If you want a custom 404 response then you need to tell `DispatcherServlet` to throw the exception if no handler is found. We can do this by setting the `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` servlet initialization parameter to `true`

a. If spring-mvc java based configuration is

```java
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) 
    {
        final DispatcherServlet servlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return servlet;
    }

}
```

b. if spring-mvc xml based configuration, initialize your dispatcher servlet like this

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

c. if spring-boot
`spring.resources.add-mappings=false` in your application.properties or yaml file.

Hope it helps